# Values from local.settings.json in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I've created an Azure function that looks like this (actually, the Microsoft template did most of the work!):

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%queue-name%", AccessRights.Listen)]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

My local.settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "..",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "..",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "..",
    "queue-name":  "testqueue"

  }
}
```

I then deployed this function.  This is a strange SO question, because my problem is that this worked immediately, but I didn't expect it to.  The function.json is here:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.0.0",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "queueName": "%queue-name%",
      "accessRights": "listen",
      "name": "myQueueItem"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\FunctionApp8.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionApp8.Function1.Run"
}
```

Clearly, the values in local.settings.json have been copied into the function settings, but i can't see them in the portal.  My question is: where are these settings now stored (queue-name and AzureWebJobsServiceBus)?

EDIT:

My Application Settings for the function:

[image: App Settings]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They'll be under the "Application settings" tab of the published function app in the Azure Portal (see picture).

There's a bit of documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings)! Note that most app settings are not published automatically, and require a bit of configuration either at the publish step or after publishing.

[image: Application settings]

---

**UPDATE**: If two functions are listening for an event on the same queue, only one function will be fired. This can cause seemingly buggy behavior, as a function will appear to fire/not fire when expected.

In this case, the unexpected behavior came from a competing functions and not an unexpected connection string.

Comment: That's what I thought, but they aren't showing there.  I've added a screenshot of my application settings

Comment: Ahh, I think I misunderstood. The settings from local.settings.json not being duplicated in the published version's app settings is expected behavior. The idea is that local.settings.json likely contains keys/secrets like connection strings, and that shouldn't be published. You'll have to go back and add AzureWebJobsServiceBus and queue-name as application settings. Your published app should then work!

Comment: They are clearly there.  Otherwise the function wouldn’t work.  I just can’t find them.

Comment: That is very strange. I'm trying to repro this issue but can't. Could you confirm that your function is truly running by looking at the logs (https://<function-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ => Debug console => CMD => LogFiles => Application => Functions => Function => <function-name> )? Since "testqueue" is a relatively common name, I wonder if another function could be consuming those messages. Something else to try is adding a new queue and listening for messages there.

Comment: You were spot-on.  It was another process that was picking up the messages; I'd come to the conclusion that it wasn't because when I tested, they stayed there for a long time (left them for 20 mins).  For some reason, the process that was picking them up seemed to sprint into life at seemingly random times!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure the function settings are taken from Application settings tab, which is the same as in App Service.

You probably published them too, go check in the portal UI.

Comment: I've added a screenshot from this tab.  As you can see - they aren't there.

Comment: @pm_2 Ok, that's interesting... How do you know your function works? Can it be it's still running locally and you confused that with running in Azure?

Comment: As I stated above, it was another process picking up the messages.  Thanks for your help.