# How to read configuration values form settings.json in dotnet core based Azure function in trigger attribue

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have an Azure Function v2 (.NET Core) project where I have created a Queue trigger type of function.

This Queue trigger attribute looks like this:

```
public static void Run(
          [QueueTrigger("myqueue-name",
          Connection = "Someconnectionstring")]string myQueueItem,
       ILogger log)
```

In the above code snippet - I want to fetch the `myqueue-name` value from `local.settings.json` file while I run locally and then add same configuration value in app settings and fetch that value when running on azure.

I search and found a solution:[Values from local.settings.json in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649237/values-from-local-settings-json-in-azure-functions)

It suggests to refer to configuration key between `%%` - this works fine if I am using Azure Function v1 (.NET Framework) - but unfortunately does not work when i am on the v2 .NET Core version of Azure function. Need help using configurable values in the `[QueueTrigger]` attribute from settings.json file or appsettings in azure

Comment: The solution should work for v2 as well, could you show us the error info or anything suspicious you meet, e.g. the console output when local debugging?

Comment: Seems like the issue was something else, I checked again and it seems to works fine. The only difference between the two samples I tried is - previously (when it did not work) - I was using CosmoDB trigger and now (which works) I am using QueueTrigger - I will try to dig more and post further details @JerryLiu

Comment: Confirmed, I am not able to reproduce the same issue. I had so many things going on - so not sure what was the issue when I posted but works fine now. Thanks for the help @JerryLiu

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly access in the attribute declaration itself. In the application settings i have `serviceBusConnectionString` and i am also using queue trigger in my code

```
   public static async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("orders", Connection = "serviceBusConnectionString")] Message myMessage, ILogger log)
   {
     //DoSomething
   }
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
So if you want the queue name also to be fetched from appSettings , Simply create an `INameResolver` to allow you to resolve any string surrounded in % (percent) signs.

```
 public static async void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%orders%", Connection = "serviceBusConnectionString")] Message myMessage, ILogger log)
       {
         //DoSomething
       }
```

and write a resolver method like this

```
public class QueueNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name].ToString();
    }
}
```

And then in your Program.cs file add the below block

```
var host = new JobHost(new JobHostConfiguration
{
  NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver()
});
host.RunAndBlock();
```

Comment: Your provided solution does not help with the question I asked - please read carefully. I wish to read configurable values from attribute declaration and not inside the method

Comment: Thanks, but still not the answer I seek - I need to set the value "orders" from azure appsettings

Comment: Your solution as mentioned in edit 2 about using %% works without the INameResolver as mentioned by Jerry

Comment: @Jsinh hope it helps